# Text Input Running Out of Div Box Child

Tags: html, css

Why the input text boxs are running out of the `div.LoginBox_Child`?
How can i contain inside?

[image]

`````css
body,
html {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvitica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: #2e849e;
  border: 1px solid #0000FF;
}

div.LoginBox_Container {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.LoginBox_Child {
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
}

input {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvitica, sans-serif;
}

.Input_Text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: block;
}

.Submit_Button {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #2e849e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #2e849e;
  display: block;
}

.Submit_Button:hover {
  background: #e69500;
  border: 1px solid #e69500;
  cursor: pointer;
}

````
`````

```html
<div class="LoginBox_Container" style="width: 20%; height: 60vh;">
  <div class="LoginBox_Child" style="width: 90%;">
    <h1>Sample</h1>
    <label for="pUser">User</label>
    <input type="text" class="Input_Text" name="pUser" maxlength="30" required>
    <label for="pPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="Input_Text" name="pPassword" maxlength="20" required>
    <input type="submit" class="Submit_Button" name="Login" value="Login">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the width of your inputs to 100%. Since you haven't defined a `box-sizing` property for the inputs, it is set to `content-box` by default. As a result, 100% is equal to the input's padding plus 100% of its parent's width. If you want to include the padding **in the width** of the input, set its `box-sizing` property to `border-box`:

`````css
body,
html {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvitica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: #2e849e;
  border: 1px solid #0000FF;
}

div.LoginBox_Container {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.LoginBox_Child {
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
}

input {
  font-family: Verdana, Helvitica, sans-serif;
}

.Input_Text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Submit_Button {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #2e849e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #2e849e;
  display: block;
}

.Submit_Button:hover {
  background: #e69500;
  border: 1px solid #e69500;
  cursor: pointer;
}

````
`````

```html
<div class="LoginBox_Container" style="width: 20%; height: 60vh;">
  <div class="LoginBox_Child" style="width: 90%;">
    <h1>Sample</h1>
    <label for="pUser">User</label>
    <input type="text" class="Input_Text" name="pUser" maxlength="30" required>
    <label for="pPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="Input_Text" name="pPassword" maxlength="20" required>
    <input type="submit" class="Submit_Button" name="Login" value="Login">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Wais. It Works. But why it don't happens with the "submit" button? Just happens for type="text"?

Comment: Oh, just add `box-sizing: border-box` to it as well. It's because it doesn't have the `Input_Text` class where I added the `box-sizing: border-box`.